# unetboot linux mint live drive boots grub2 instead of unetboot

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, live-usb, unetbootin

I screwed up big time, I have installed linux mint live disk on my flash drive via unetboot on an virtualised linux mint of another computer. When I transferred the usb drive to my main computer, it DOESN'T show up the unetboot selection screen but instead, always shows grub2 and it's boot options only into my main OS.([which doesn't work at the moment, see my other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297031/unable-to-boot-after-installing-after-systemd-update))

Before that, I have installed grub2 on the almost everything including the usb drive for some reason via boot repair, I am sure that is what causes this problem, not sure why I did it. It doesn't matter if I format and install the OS on my usb drive, the incorrect grub2 menu always appears. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the USB image writer on my virtualised linux mint and this time with usb 2 to write the linux mint ISO, IT WORKS! I am able to boot to live disk on my main computer